# How to grant both Git and Apache permissions to /var/www

Tags: git, permissions, capistrano, lamp

> I am attempting to install wp-deploy. After reinstalling Mint three
>   times and nearly burning down my house with my rage I cannot for the
>   life of me figure out how I am supposed to give `/var/www` the right
>   permissions.
>
> I get a permission denied, if git attempts to write which will be
>   happening semi-frequently with capistrano/wp-deploy.
>
> But if I `chown` the directory I break apache.
>
> `drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www` is the current permissions where `www` is
>   a group. Some tutorial told me to make that contains the www-data user
>   and another user, but it didnt seem to change the behaviors. I have
>   also had this at `www-data:root` and `www-data:www-data` all with the
>   same behaviors.

UPDATE:  Still a mess, updated and then realized some mistakes. I'll probably be back with more info soon. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Since this question has nothing to do with programming,  post your next inquiry on https://serverfault.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

> Some tutorial told me to make that contains the www-data user and another user, but it didnt seem to change the behaviors.

That is the usual way to do it: If more than one user needs to access a directory, one creates a group, gives that group ownership of the directory and sets the permission for that group. After that all the users who need to access the directory get added to the group. **However, note that group membership changes usually only take effect after the user's next login.** That is, if the user is still logged in while being added to the group, the user will not notice the change until the next login.

Given that there already is a `www` group, you just need to check the permissions are correct and then add the Git user (let's call that one `gituser`) to the `www` group with [usermod](https://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod):

```
sudo usermod -a -G www gituser
```

The flag `-a` appends the given group to existing group list of the user. and `-G` takes a comma seperated list of groups that the user should be part of.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response. I realized when i woke up and saw it this morning that half of my errors went away in the night when I shut down my computer and relogged lololol fml.

Answer (score 1):

You want to separate the permissions. It is usually a bad idea to give Apache write access to directories, unless specifically needed(and not accessible from the web).

`chown` the files to the git user and the `chgrp` group to www(should already be that way)
Make sure the `www-data` user is a member of the `www` group `groups www-data`, if not add it `usermod -g www www-data` and restart the apache service.

Set the permissions on the `/var/www` and all *directories* under it to "755".
Resulting in `drwxr-xr-x`.

Set the *file* permissions to "644" for all files under `/var/www` and its sub-directories files. Resulting in `-rw-r--r--`.

```
find /var/www -f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: so I have followed these instructions and git is able to write and wordpress is served, however, wordpress cannot write to it's own directory. It was my understanding that wordpress just needed www-data permissions which it has. Currently all directories have been recursively chowned and given www-data:www where www is a group containing my user and www-data. They also have 755 ( I dont know how to 644 only the files but its my understanding that this shouldnt pertain to the error I am receiving but is a security measure, please correct me if I am wrong. ) Any ideas?

Comment: @JeremyDixon, A base install of WP usually does not need more permissions. Some plugins, and some configuration options, do require writable directories. They are all located under wp-content, change those directories to 775.